# Проблемы одновременного доступа к in-memory базе из разных юнит-тестов

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nunit

У меня в юнит-тестах на базе nUnit есть странное поведение контекста in-memory базы, которое я не знаю как объяснить (хотя и легко понял, как избежать)

Ситуация такая. Я хотел поглубже разобраться с тем, как запускаются паралельно тесты и как они получают доступ к одной и той же базе данных.

Для простоты вот какая модель. Два теста, получают базу в которой есть одна Person (id = 3), проверяют, что в базе одна сущность (что ничего соседний тест не вставил), потом добавляют в базу ещё одну сущность и проверяют, что теперь записей в таблице стало два.

Сами тесты:

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestBoth : ContactsTestBase
{
    [Test]
    public async Task TestA()
    {
        var context = GetDbContext("MemoryDb1");

        Assert.IsTrue(context.Contacts.Count() == 1, "!1");

        await this.Create(context, GetContact());

        Assert.IsTrue(context.Contacts.Count() == 2, "!2");

        //CleanupDb(context);
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task TestB()
    {
        var context = GetDbContext("MemoryDb1");

        Assert.IsTrue(context.Contacts.Count() == 1, "!1");

        await this.Create(context, GetContact());

        Assert.IsTrue(context.Contacts.Count() == 2, "!2");

        //CleanupDb(context);
    }
}
```

Вспомогательные классы:

```
public class TestBase
{
    protected CancellationToken GetCancellationToken()
    {
        return new CancellationTokenSource().Token;
    }

    private static DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> GetDbOptions(string databaseName)
    {
        return new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDbContext>()
               .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName)
               .Options;
    }

    protected static AppDbContext GetDbContext(string databaseName)
    {
        var context = new AppDbContext(GetDbOptions(databaseName));

        context.Contacts.Add(new Contact { Id = 3, Title = "3" });
        context.SaveChanges();

        return context;
    }

    protected static void CleanupDb(AppDbContext context)
    {
        if (context.Database.IsInMemory())
        {
            context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
        }
    }
}

public class ContactsTestBase : TestBase
{
    protected Task<ContactData> Create(AppDbContext context, Contact contact)
    {
        return this.Create1(context, contact);
    }

    private async Task<ContactData> Create1(AppDbContext context, Contact contact)
    {
        var cancellationToken = this.GetCancellationToken();
        await context.Contacts.AddAsync(contact, cancellationToken);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        return null; // not used, but maybe should return something like a Task.FromResult
    }

    // Проблема не в Mediatr, проверено.
    private Task<ContactData> Create2(AppDbContext context, Contact contact)
    {
        var request = new ContactData(contact.Id, contact.Title);
        var command = new Command(request);
        var handler = new Handler(context);
        return handler.Handle(command, this.GetCancellationToken());
    }

    protected static Contact GetContact()
    {
        var contact = new Contact { Id = 0, Title = "10" };
        return contact;
    }
}
```

Вот какое поведение проявляется: сами тесты поодиночке отрабатывают отлично, но как только запускаешь сразу всю пачку (пробовал разносить их по разным классам - поведение сохраняется), то один из тестов выдаёт ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> System.ArgumentException : An item with the same key has already been
>   added. Key: 3    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryInsert(TKey key, TValue
>   value, InsertionBehavior behavior)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory.Storage.Internal.InMemoryTable`1.Create(IUpdateEntry
>   entry)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory.Storage.Internal.InMemoryStore.ExecuteTransaction(IReadOnlyList`1
>   entries, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 updateLogger)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1
>   entriesToSave)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean
>   acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean
>   acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)    at Tests.TestBase.GetDbContext(String
>   databaseName) in C:\temp\Contest\Tests\TestBase.cs:line 27    at
>   Tests.TestBoth.TestB() in C:\temp\Contest\Tests\TestBoth.cs:line 27
>
>   at
>   NUnit.Framework.Internal.TaskAwaitAdapter.GenericAdapter`1.GetResult()
>   in
>   D:\a\1\s\src\NUnitFramework\framework\Internal\TaskAwaitAdapter.cs:line
>   99    at NUnit.Framework.Internal.AsyncToSyncAdapter.Await(Func`1
>   invoke) in
>   D:\a\1\s\src\NUnitFramework\framework\Internal\AsyncToSyncAdapter.cs:line
>   60    at
>   NUnit.Framework.Internal.Commands.TestMethodCommand.Execute(TestExecutionContext
>   context) in
>   D:\a\1\s\src\NUnitFramework\framework\Internal\Commands\TestMethodCommand.cs:line
>   64    at
>   NUnit.Framework.Internal.Execution.SimpleWorkItem.PerformWork() in
>   D:\a\1\s\src\NUnitFramework\framework\Internal\Execution\SimpleWorkItem.cs:line
>   58

Разумеется ошибка пропадает если запускать тесты в MemoryDb1 и MemoryDb2, либо если раскомментировать CleanupDb (почему?). Но меня интересует не как избавиться от ошибки "в лоб", у меня непонимание механики происходящего, чтобы в будущем писать тесты, которые будут нормально изолированы.

Comment: Каждый тест пытается выполнить добавление записи с Id-3, поэтому и падает, вроде все логично? А т.к. inmemory у вас одноименные, то это одна и та же БД, я так понимаю.

Comment: Да, это странная ситуация. Все происходит так как будто `var context = GetDbContext("MemoryDb1")` не переменная в методе, а поле класса.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.inmemorydbcontextoptionsextensions.useinmemorydatabase?view=efcore-3.1  Configures the context to connect to a named in-memory database. The in-memory database is shared anywhere the same name is used, but only for a given service provider.

Comment: @Monk Вполне тянет на ответ текущего вопроса. Итого, если вернуться к исходному вопросу (для чего вообще все эти эксперименты затевал) - как для очередного теста получить заданную базу: нужно разделять разными именами баз для разных случаев. Прямо вот пусть имя базы складывается из неймспейса тестового класса, его имени и имени тесткейса.

Comment: Не силен в EntityFramework, но разве база позволяет создать `Contact` с одинаковым id? Вы в тесте создаете в одной и той же базе одинаковую сущность. Видимо, ваш `Assert` в тесте Б, срабатывает раньше, чем `await this.Create(context, GetContact());` в тесте A. Попробуйте создавать сущность `contract` с разными `Id`. Что будет в таком случае?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko Строго говоря ответ на ваш вопрос - "EF не позволяет", но вообще он просто назначит новые реальные ID создаваемым сущностям. Запускать один тест можно хоть сто записей сделать: проблемы начинаются именно при взаимодействии двух паралельных тестов, при этом вроде ничего не мешало корректно создавать сначала одну сущность из одного теста, потом из другого, потом опять из первого, потом из второго - и так хоть сто раз. Проблема как раз в том, что EF увидел две detach сущности как одну: он должен был понять, что это две разные сущности из двух разных тестов и дать им разные id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала, почему так происходит.
Согласно [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.inmemorydbcontextoptionsextensions.useinmemorydatabase?view=efcore-3.1) метод `UseInMemoryDatabase` позволяет параллельный доступ к БД по имени.

> The in-memory database is shared anywhere the same name is used

Таким образом, когда вы в двух тестах обращаетесь к одной и той же БД, с одной и той же операцией, происходит ошибка.

---

Делить БД между тестами, которые зависят от её состояния - плохая идея, а значит лучше всего в данной ситуации будет обращаться к разным БД. В NUnit у теста есть контекст, навскидку - доступ получается примерно как `TestContext.CurrentContext`. Два варианта уникального параметра теста - `ID` или `FullName` для читаемости, но у `FullName` я например не помню, учитываются ли параметры теста, что может быть важно.